# change in size of an individual pixel?

Tags: image-processing

If we want to change resolution of an  image,we can achieve that by increasing or decreasing the number of pixels

Is there any other way ? Can we change dimensions of an indvidual pixel,rather then changing the number/count of total available pixels?

by changing size of pixel,i mean changing the width and height of array/matrix containg pixel value

Comment: a pixel is just a value. It doesn't have a size.

Comment: your edit is a paradoxon: "changing the width and height of the matrix containing pixel values" is the opposite of "not changing the number of total pixels"

Answer (score 1):

A 100x100 pixel image is always a 100x100 pixel image.

You can print it with 100 DPI printer, and it will produce 1x1 inch picture.
A 50 DPI printer will produce 2x2 inch picture because it makes dots that are twice as big.

Same thing when viewing 100x100 image on 15" laptop with 1280x720 screen, it is larger because the pixels are larger than when viewing on a 15" laptop with 1920x1080 screen.

Or same thing when viewing the 100x100 image on 24" 1920x1080 screen, the image is smaller than when viewing the same image on 32" 1920x1080 screen.

Comment: what do you mean by"1x1 inch picture"  ? 1X1 pixel size??